# The lastModifyingUser of a Google Docs Revision does not show the most recent editor of each version. Intended?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a Google Doc and a Google Sheet with a script which checks the Doc every hour and, if a change has been made, sends out an email to the editors and owner of the Doc.

I would like to improve this script by excluding whomever made the most recent change so that they don't receive an update email for their own change. However, I've run into an issue with the information I get from the list of Revisions: the lastModifyingUser from each revision seems to be pegged to the oldest User that made a change, not the newest. Alternatively, it's reporting who made the first change on a version of a document, but I want the 'last' meaning most recent.

Consider this example history of a single version/revision:
10:05 am, Person A

10:07 am, Person B

10:08 am, Person B

What I am seeing is that the lastModifyingUser of this revision will always be Person A even after 10:07. I would expect that it would be Person B if checked at 10:09 or later.
I have a couple of questions related to this:

1) Is this the intended result of the lastModifyingUser property?

2) Is there a different way to see who most recently changed a document, even if it is in the same version?

3) Does anyone know the minimum time between edits which will result in different versions?

4) Can I change a Doc's settings to force each edit to be its own version?

Thank you for any insights,

Comment: Having the same issue. I've noticed that the expected behaviour actually occurs when you call File:get - the lastModifyingUser property on the result is actually set correctly for the file's current revision.